# How to set different CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS depends on different add_executable?

Tags: cmake

I'm working on testing my code on some micro-controllers, (instead of using `CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE`, I set `CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS` directly in my CmakeLists) each platform has it's own `CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS`.

I set different targets(add_executable) for different platform, but I can't find a way to set different `CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS` to each target individually.

So is there any way I can do this?

Comment: `set_target_properties(target_name PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS ...)` or the configuration dependent property LINK_FLAGS_<CONFIG> should be applied in this case.

Comment: @vre how could I miss this :(